# Split array into two arrays based on the first character of each element

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements, filtering, grouping

I have null-based array consisting of string values:

```
array
  0 => string 'Message 1' (length=9)
  1 => string '%company' (length=8)
  2 => string 'Message 2' (length=9)
  3 => string '%name' (length=5)
```

I need to pick all values starting with `%` and ideally put them into another array.

```
array
  0 => string 'Message 1' (length=9)
  1 => string 'Message 2' (length=9)

array
  0 => string '%company' (length=8)
  1 => string '%name' (length=5)
```

The first array is the result of a validation function, and since I hate, when a validator returns information about required inputs in a million lines (like: this is required `<br><br>` that is required...), instead of outputting real messages, I want to output the names of the required and unfilled inputs, to be put into nice one message 'Fields this, that and even that are mandatory'.

Comment: foreach($array as $string)if($string[0] == '%'){do smething}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PHP >5.3, below that you need to use [create_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php).

This solution first filters the original array, and gets the items that begin with `%`. Then [array_diff()](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) is used to get the array with the remaining values.

```
$array_percent = array_filter($orig_array, function ($v) {
  return substr($v, 0, 1) === '%';
});

$array_others = array_diff($orig_array, $array_percent);
```

Comment: strpos($v, '%') === 0 will be faster.

Answer (score 8):

Apologies for resurrecting the question, but simple filtering like this is *super simple* with [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep).

```
$subject  = array('Message 1', '%company', 'Message 2', '%name');

$percents = preg_grep('/^%/', $subject);
$others   = preg_grep('/^%/', $subject, PREG_GREP_INVERT); 

var_dump($percents, $others);
```

Comment: I though think that the second preg grep should be replaces with an array diff. Otherwise the same work will be done twice.

Comment: I don't think it should, mostly because it's demonstrating that you can use the invert flag.

Answer (score 5):

This is some simple partitioning code using [`array_walk()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and an anonymous callback.

```
$result1 = array();
$result2 = array();
array_walk($array, function($v) use (&$result1, &$result2) {
    if ($v[0] == '%') {
        $result1[] = $v;
    } else {
        $result2[] = $v;
    }
});
```

Putting that into some reusable code:

```
function partition($array, $callback) {
    $resultTrue  = array();
    $resultFalse = array();
    array_walk($array, function($v) use (&$resultTrue, &$resultFalse, $callback) {
        if (call_user_func($callback, $v) === true) {
            $resultTrue[] = $v;
        } else {
            $resultFalse[] = $v;
        }
    });
    return array($resultTrue, $resultFalse);
}

// and put to use:
$partitionedData = partition($array, function($v) {
    return $v[0] == '%';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) with a [callback](http://php.net/callback),

```
<?php
$array = array(
  0 => 'Message 1' ,
  1 => '%company' ,
  2 => 'Message 2' ,
  3 => '%name' );

  function start_with($var)
  {
      return $var[0] == '%';
  }

  function dont_start_with($var)
  {
      return $var[0] != '%';
  }

  $startw = array_filter($dizi,'start_with'); // filtering elements
  $startw = array_values($startw);  // reseting indexes.

  $nstartw = array_filter($dizi,'dont_start_with');
  $nstartw = array_values($nstartw);

  var_dump($startw , $nstartw);
?>
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you :) I have however little problem with that dual filtering ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
$array2=array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
   if($value[0] =='%')
   { 
     $array2[]=$value;
     unset($array[$key]);
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

after unset you can either use `foreach` loop to iterate array can use `array_values` function to construct new array

Comment: Please don't use the `{}`-syntax to access characters in a string - use `[]` instead (`{}` is deprecated). Another thing is, that `$array` is not a continuous integer-indexed array any more (due to using `unset()`).

Comment: @Stafan – re `{}` thank you, re: integer-indexed – simple array_values will reset the index :)